# Required radio buttons HTML / Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm making a sentiment analysis UI using Flask and HTML5. On the homepage html page (linked from Flask using render_template), I have radio buttons. I have a custom message and a "required" setting so that if a radio button is not selected and the user tries to hit "submit", a message shows up and the user is not able to submit.
The problem is that if a radio button is not selected, the message will not go away, and will not allow the user to submit their answer even if they do select a button. The page must be refreshed to escape this.

If I remove the whole "onvalid" part and just leave the "required" part, it works totally fine, but then I lose the custom message and just have a default one. I would be grateful if somebody could help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it.

Thanks very much in advance. Here's the section of the code that's bugging (specifically the 4th line):

```
<form method="post"><center class='sansserif'>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=1 oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Please select a rating before continuing.')" required="required"> Very negative<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=2> Negative<br>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=3> Neutral<br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=4> Positive<br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=5> Very Positive 
</center></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><br></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="English" value= 'checked'> <em> This sentence is in English</em></center><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using Flask-WTF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jquery` to 1. display a message if a radio button is not selected and 2. If the user clicks a radio button, the original message will be removed

```
<html>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=1> Very negative<br>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=2> Negative<br>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=3> Neutral<br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=4> Positive<br></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="radio" name="sentiment" value=5> Very Positive 
</center></td>
</tr>
<tr><td><br></td></tr>
<tr>
<td><center><input type="checkbox" name="English" value= 'checked'> <em> This 
 sentence is in English</em></center><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><button class='get_input'>Sumit</button></td>
</tr>
<div class='user_warning_message'></div>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.get_input').click(function() {
   if ($('input[name=sentiment]:checked').length === 0) {
    $('.user_warning_message').html('<div style="width:100px;height:50px;background-color:red">checkbox not selected</div>');
    }
  });
  $("input[name='sentiment']").change(function(){
    $('.user_warning_message').html('');
  });
});
 </script>
</html>
```

[image]

---

This current solution will display the error message should the button be clicked without any radio buttons selected, and will clear the message if one of the radio buttons is again selected.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply, but I'm only using Python, not Jquery.